# No reconoce las variables de entorno con el MVN

Tags: maven

He descomprimido maven 3.8.4 en c: se crea la carpeta apache-maven-3.8.4. Tengo las variables de entorno:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas en el path

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que el `mvn -v` dice que no reconoce el comando mvn.

Comment: La 3.8.3 si funciona no se porque le .4 no

Comment: Te faltó decir cuál es tu pregunta. Vemos unas variables de entorno... y qué falla?

Comment: el mvn -v dice que no reconoce el comando mvn

Comment: Ah pues es porque en el PATH debe estar ese MAVEN_HOME, que es donde están los binarios. En M2 es el directorio donde maven busca algún settings.xml y pone la carpeta repository con todas las dependencias que jalas, a forma de caché

Comment: te aseguraste de cerrar y volver a abrir tu terminal para que aplicara cambios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la variable de entorno del PATH debería ser `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`.